# Having doxygen aware of namespace in cpp

Tags: c++, doxygen

We have a c++ project that we document using doxygen, putting only doxygen comments inside headers for classes, we document static functions inside cpp.

Our doxygen configuration files harvest any header /hpp) / implementation /cpp) file inside the project. In addition, we have quite a few independant components (and externals) that we isolate inside namespaces.

The project is done in a way that we use polymorphism (due to extensive use of proxy pattern)

As it's a common practice, we forbid the *using* directive inside the header and we use it in implementation file.

Typically, we have in header:

```
/**
 * @brief
 *   test from A
 */
void f(N1::N2::A);
/**
 * @brief
 *   test from A
 */
void f(N1::N2::B);
```

Inside the implementation, we have

```
using namespace N1::N2;

void f(A) { }
void f(B) { }
```

When running doxygen, he seems confused and produces error messages:

```
warning: no uniquely matching class member found for f(A)
possible candidates:
void f(N1::N2::A)
void f(N1::N2::B)
```

Any idea how to get rid of these errors and make doxygen aware of the "using" directive ?

**EDIT**

- bad news, seems to be opened on bug tracker : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=617285 , https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154880 : looks like I'm looking for a workaround rather than a clean solution.

Comment: In general, if you want name-accurate lookups on C++ code, you need a full C++ front end.  AFAICT, Doxygen does not have a full C++ end.  (Because of this, I've always wondered at how C++ users could be so enamored with Doxygen; lack of anything better?)  If you're lucky, you'll find a workaround for special cases.

Comment: Lack of better, definitely. This one is widely available and deals with C as well...

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer and accept it, at least until the bug is fixed.

Comment: I'm still looking for a workaround so I'm keeping the question open. If no one can provide a workaround, I'll close and add an answer

Comment: Thanks for the question and pointer to the bug. I'm having very similar issues here, but I guess without a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No workaround found, we reverted to use full namespace in implementation to match exactly with headers definition. Marking it as closed, my loss :-(
Seeing comments / edit in the question might help reader